# Normals issue when applying "solidify" modifier

Tags: normals, solidify-modifier

This doll´s hand´s mesh seems to be ok until I apply "solidfy".
I did mesh>normals>recalculate outside & recalculate inside
I applied EdgeSplit modifier (as they suggested in other answers)
Nothing happens.
In geometry>face orientation nothing is shown also

Any idea?

(thanks a lot)[image]

Hi you all.
I made what you asked and suddenly it seems not to distort so heavily. Anyway, it still distorts.
The only diference between picture 1 and 2: solidify applied with Rim> fill, Offset> 1.0000, and Thickness> 0.002m

[image]

It seems to have something to do with the mesh, despite it is quite simple. The distortion evolves from the simple mesh to the chaos in some points, as in the slot and one of the two holes I made in the sides ... Any idea for cleaning that mesh up?
[image]

Comment: The mesh blows up like this once you apply the modifier ? can you show it without modifier ?

Comment: hello could you please share your file with the modifier unapplied? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: hard to say without the file, also, why do you need thickness?

Comment: Because I wan to print this